# Print Oracle queries in file

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have several application connected to Oracle 11g server. I would like to print all SQL queries executed into the database into text file. Is this possible?

Comment: `SELECT SQL_FULLTEXT FROM V$SQLAREA`